# Warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision..."

Tags: arrays, cocoa, warnings, nstableview

I am doing a shopping cart tutorial: I have an array that collects input from a text field, and then displays it in the NSTableView. You can check an item, and remove it from the list. I want to display a warning only if something is checked. So, I have this:

```
    -(IBAction)removeItemFromShoppingList:(id)sender {
        int selectedItemIndex = [shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
        if (selectedItemIndex == -1) return;
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        ...
        [alert runModal];
        [alert release];
}
```

On line 2 here (`int selectedItemIndex...`) I get a yellow warning: **Implicit conversion loses integer precision:’NSInteger’ (aka ‘long’) to ‘int’.**

Why?

Comment: Maybe because an int is shorter than a long?

Comment: As an aside, you should only see this warning when building for the simulator since NSInteger is 32 bits when building for the device. As others have said, you should use the same precision types or explicitly cast to say "I know for a fact this will never be larger than 32 bytes".

Comment: What do you mean "only building for the simulator"? (It's for a Mac application, not iOS)

Comment: To remove warning: int selectedItemIndex = (int)[shoppingListTableView selectedRow];

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From apple's documentation:

> When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer.

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

**UPDATE:**

Explain in detail:

`[shoppingListTableView selectedRow]` returns a NSInteger, and you are building an 64-bit application, so it is in fact a `long`.

You can use `long selectedItemIndex` instead of `int selectedItemIndex` to suppress this warning, but the warning appears again when building 32-bit version.

A better way is using `NSInteger selectedItemIndex`, which handles this case correctly.

Comment: I got error "Typedef redefinition with different types long vs int"

Comment: @KunalBalani and justicepenny you aren't supposed to try to add this code to your project. This is only showing how NSInteger is defined internally.

Answer (score 8):

Because your variable is of type `int` and you are trying to copy the value of a variable of type `NSInteger` into it. An `NSInteger` can hold larger values than an `int` can, so you get a warning that overflow is possible. Probably the simplest fix is to change `int` to `NSInteger`. (When you want to copy the value of a variable to run tests on it, you should usually use a variable of the same type.)

Comment: Ok, I am surprised to get this, since I copied the tutorial from the book! It was written for XC3, so maybe that's the issue? (Or a typo in the book?)

Comment: If folks who wrote books were great programmers,  they'd be shipping products instead of books!  :)

Comment: @Fletch , I noticed that the sample code that doesn't show the warning is for SDK 10.6, my project is for 10.7 - it shows the warning!

Comment: Probably due to some tools changes.  By default, projects now use LLVM/Clang as the compiler and static analyzer, where as in previous Xcode releases, the compiler of choice was gcc.  LLVM is able to give much better feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
int selectedItemIndex = (int)[shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
```

Instead of

```
int selectedItemIndex = [shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
```

Answer (score 2):

The selectedRow: method returns a value of type NSInteger.

You should make your selectedItemIndex of type NSInteger.

Please refer to:

> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   NSInteger selectedItemIndex = [shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
```

Instead of

```
   int selectedItemIndex = [shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update project settings, to remove all

`Implicit conversion loses integer precision` warnings, by setting

`Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type` to `No`

in project's build settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get out warning just do:

```
int selectedItemIndex = (int)[shoppingListTableView selectedRow];
```