# NSString stringWithFormat "implicit conversion loses integer precision"

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, implicit-conversion, stringwithformat

Im trying to save a high score using

```
 HighScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"ScoreSaved"];
 Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %i", HighScore];
```

it says :

> "implicit conversion loses integer precision, NSInterger(aka long) to
>   int

```
-(void)EndGame
{

if (ScoreNumber > HighScore){
    HighScore = ScoreNumber;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"ScoreSaved"];
}
```

this is my first game and i am stuck how would i save a high score?
thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Please read some Objective C code conventions first. Variables and method signatures should begin with a lower case character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813799/warning-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision)

Comment: 64 bits issue. Your warning message is explicit, XCode even proposes to correct it (if you click on the warning). I'm sure on SO there is question about it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong specifier with `stringWithFormat`, however getting the right one is difficult if you want to support both 32- and 64-bit targets.  It's often easier to use `%ld` and cast the value to `long`:

```
Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %ld", (long)HighScore];
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a wrong format specifier in your string formatting which causes an imporper conversion for the `HighScore` variable (`NSInteger`).

Use the `%ld` specifier which is intended for `NSInteger` types :

```
Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %ld", HighScore];
```